# Bind jQuery to Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am populating a table with some data. I do not know how many rows the table contains. Each row has a link which if I click shows me the details of the said row.

Now I wish to bind a single jQuery to each of these hyperlinks. This function will receive the unique id of each row; and do an ajax to fetch more data for the row:

Here is what the HTML looks like (with id being an actual number):

```
<a id="view-id">
    <img src="/resources/assets/graphics/view.png" class="action-button" alt="View" title="View" />
</a>
```

My jQuery function will look like so (with id being an actual number):

```
$(document).on('click', '#view-id', function() {
    //Do Something
});
```

Since I do not know how many row's I will have; how can I bind my jQuery function to each of these hyperlink elements.

I read somewhere that I can do the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#view-1,#view-2,#view-3', function() {
```

But this doesn't seem very efficient. Any ideas which direction I should head in. Bear in mind the table content is loaded via an AJAX call : )

Thanks.

Comment: Usually in this case a `class` selector is used. You can still retrieve the id of the element clicked with a `this.id` in case you need to know the specific `id` within the listener function.

Comment: Keep in mind that it's better to bind click handlers to the closest element that will not be removed instead of just using `document`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign a class to the elements to be bound, and use the class name in the selector to select all of the elements with that class.  The $(this) will reference the object clicked, at which point you can do $(this).id to get the clicked object's ID.

HTML:

```
<a id="view-id1" class="class-name">
    <img src="/resources/assets/graphics/view.png" class="action-button" alt="View" title="View" />
</a>
<a id="view-id2" class="class-name">
    <img src="/resources/assets/graphics/view.png" class="action-button" alt="View" title="View" />
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class-name', function() {
    // 'this' references the item clicked.
    alert(this.id + ' is the ID clicked.');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a class to all the elements and then use that class to target the anchor element

```
<a id="view-id" class="view-id">
    <img src="/resources/assets/graphics/view.png" class="action-button" alt="View" title="View" />
</a>
```

then

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-id', function() {
    //Do Something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a class to each of those elements and bind them using the class selector?

```
<a id="view-id" class="view-item">
<img src="/resources/assets/graphics/view.png" class="action-button" alt="View" title="View" /></a>

$(document).on('click', '.view-item', function() {
    //Do Something
});
```

Comment: That would work in firing the function. But how do I get to know which unique link it was that did so? I would still need the unique ID to make AJAX call.

Comment: The ID will be accessible through $(this).id.  See example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#abc, #xyz, #pqr').bind('click', function () {
      alert("hello");
});
```

Use comma with multiple elements with id, OR elements to bind event.